# Autocreation of folder in every location I worked

Tags: mkdir

I share my user with a few people.
I have an issue: every time I work in a directory, another directory inside my working directory is created. 
I checked my alias, bashrc - no any command to create a dir automatically.
Where I should check more to find the command for autocreation of this dir?

Comment: What is the name of directory? what is the output of this commands: `mkdir ~/foobar; cd ~/foobar; ls -la`

Comment: drwxrwxrwx 5 root     root     4096 Oct 15 19:35 .
drwxr-xr-x 6 root     root     4096 Oct 15 19:33 ..